# Select first row in each GROUP BY group

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a requirement in my project that I have this data with me:

```
C1 | C2 | C3 | C4
A  | B  | 2  | X
A  | B  | 3  | Y
C  | D  | 4  | Q
C  | D  | 1  | P
```

Where C1, C2, C3 and C4 are columns name in Database

And I have need to show data like this

```
C1 | C2 | C3 | C4
A  | B  | 5  | X
C  | D  | 5  | Q
```

Comment: Do you know what `group by` is?

Comment: What do you mean by "first"? If you swap X and Y or P and Q under C4, is the expected output still the same?

Comment: @AaronBertrand  I have just edited my question.Swapped 3rd and 4th row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes I know but what about 4th column.Is it normal situation ?

Comment: @user3517064 . . . There is no concept of "first" in a SQL table.  You need a separate column to define ordering.  Do you have another such column?

Comment: How will anyone know whether that second row of output should be Q or P? How will they verify that Q was "first" (aside from the fact that it happens to come out that way, at this instance, when you [SELECT without ORDER BY](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior.aspx))? Also, shouldn't the sum for C and D be 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is fairly simple. Just follow my solution below:

```
--CREATE THE SAMPLE TABLE
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (C1 char(1) NULL, C2 char(1) NULL, C3 int NULL, C4 char(1) NULL);
GO

--INSERT THE SAMPLE VALUES
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('A', 'B', 2, 'X'), ('A', 'B', 3, 'Y'), ('C', 'D', 4, 'Q'), ('C','D', 1, 'P');
GO

--SELECT SUM(C3) AND GROUP BY ONLY C1 AND C2, THEN SELECT TOP 1 ONLY FROM C4
SELECT 
    C1, 
    C2, 
    SUM(C3) AS C3, 
    (SELECT TOP(1) C4 FROM TABLE1 AS B WHERE A.C1 = B.C1) AS C4 
FROM 
    TABLE1 AS A 
GROUP BY 
    C1, 
    C2;
GO

--CLEAN UP THE DATABASE, DROP THE SAMPLE TABLE
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'TABLE1')) DROP TABLE TABLE1;
GO
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the first record ordered by `c4` (grouped by `c1` and `c2`), then this will work establishing a `row_number` and using `max` with `case`:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by c1, c2 order by c4) rn
  from yourtable
) 
select c1, c2, sum(c3), max(case when rn = 1 then c4 end) c4
from cte 
group by c1, c2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9bfe/1)

However, if you don't want to order by `c4`, then you need some other column to ensure the correct order of the results.  Without an order by clause, there's no guarantee on how they are returned.

Comment: Thank's for your reply,but i just want to fetch first value whatever it is not the max.The row which comes first its column value.

Comment: I have just edited (swapped 3rd and 4th row) can you please once again review the output.

Comment: @user3517064 -- `max` doesn't take the max as you're thinking, it's aggregating on the row number column and only show the first row.  The key here is `row_number() over (partition by c1, c2 order by c4) rn`.  Specifically, you need to know how to order the row number.  I've used c4, but without ordering by a specific column, you can't know for sure the order of the results.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you choose 'X' and 'Q' as those rows where inserted first, while grouping C1 and C2.
I would suggest you to add an identity column in your table and work based on it as given below.

Table:

```
DECLARE @DB TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),C1 VARCHAR(10),C2 VARCHAR(10),C3 INT,C4 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @DB VALUES 
('A','B',2,'X'),
('A','B',3,'Y'),
('C','D',4,'Q'),
('C','D',1,'P')
```

Code:

```
SELECT  A.*,B.C4
FROM    (
        SELECT      C1,C2,SUM(C3) C3 FROM @DB
        GROUP BY    C1,C2) A
JOIN
        (
        SELECT  C1,C2,C4 FROM (
        SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1,C2 ORDER BY ID) [ROW]
        FROM    @DB) LU WHERE LU.ROW = 1) B
ON      A.C1 = B.C1 AND A.C2 = B.C2
```

Result:

[image]